# Cannot compile an opencv source file (C++) using 'pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv'

Tags: compiling, gcc, g++

I compiled an opencv file (C++) using command line

```
g++ facedetect.cpp -o facedetect 'pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv'
```

but I had error

```
g++: error: pkg-config --cflags opencv: No such file or directory 
g++: error: pkg-config --libs opencv: No such file or directory
```

Whereas when I copy the libraries from this command:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

And paste it manually to the g++ command, then it runs. The problem is that it cannot recognize the libraries from `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`, but I don't know how to fix it. If someone has experience about this, please help me to solve it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

To get the output from a command inserted into another command, use `$(...)` syntax.

```
g++ facedetect.cpp -o facedetect $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)
```

Answer (score 3):

You used the wrong quotes.  You should have used the backtic `  not the apostrophe '  .  Or has been pointed out, the $(  ) construct works too, and even allows nesting.